# Environment set up for running a falcon app

Tags: pycharm, gunicorn, falconframework

I've a simple falcon app which I'm running on the terminal using the following command,

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 main:app --reload
```

main.py is the python file which instantiates app = falcon.API(). This works.

So I tried to set this config inside of PyCharm. But this I can't get to run. Here's the PyCharm config window

[image]

Can someone help me configure this window to get the app running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you almost got it right already, except you need to set the script to the `gunicorn` of your virtual environment, and put the parameters in the appropriate input box.

Use the "three dots" button to the right of the `script` input box, and navigate to the virtual environment, there you should find a `bin/` directory, inside there should be `gunicorn`. Selecting this should have you end up with your input box like this:

```
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn
```

No parameters, these go into the `script parameters` input box below like this:

```
-b 0.0.0.0:5000 main:app
```

In the input box `working directory`, you set it to the working directory of your app, like this:

```
/path/to/appdirectory
```

It is possible that you need to enable `gevent compatible` for the debugger, which you can set in `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger` with a checkbox.

Comment: thanks for that, I though wrapped everything into a java main function and just called the script.

Comment: This worked for uvicorn as well.